# windows network password required for share

Tags: networking, password, samba

I want two-way sharing between Windows 7 and Ubuntu Studio 14. I never used Ubuntu before, but I managed to get it to work one way (I used Samba to share one of my Ubuntu partitions, now I have acess to it from the Windows computer without any problems).

But now I'm trying to access a NTFS partition on the Windows computer from Ubuntu and can't get it to work.

Within Windows I checked "access for everyone" for that drive, in the sharing settings I gave everyone permission to read and write everything. I deactivated password protections, even for public. Nevertheless, if I try to get access to that drive from within Ubuntu, it is listed twice: Once with the name, I gave it under Windows ("Program and Data on D"). If I click on that I get "Failed to open "Programs and Data on D. Failed to mount Windows share: Permission denied." And then there is "D$" which is not affected by the renaming. If I click on that, I'm still asked for a 
password. And if I enter the correct password and group name (The way it is set in Windows), it is not accepted (Message: Password required for share).

I found out that I have access to the public user folder (read and write) without any password prompt, but not to that drive.

I fiddled around a bit with smb.conf, this is how it looks at the moment (I don't know, if Samba has influence on how a shared drive on Windows appears in Linux):

```
#
                # Sample configuration file for the Samba suite for Debian GNU/Linux.
                #
                #
            # This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
            # smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
            # here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options most of which 
            # are not shown in this example
            #
            # Some options that are often worth tuning have been included as
            # commented-out examples in this file.
            #  - When such options are commented with ";", the proposed setting
            #    differs from the default Samba behaviour
            #  - When commented with "#", the proposed setting is the default
            #    behaviour of Samba but the option is considered important
            #    enough to be mentioned here
            #
            # NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command
            # "testparm" to check that you have not made any basic syntactic 
            # errors. 

            #======================= Global Settings =======================

            [global]

            ## Browsing/Identification ###

            # Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
                workgroup = GRUPPEXXX
            ;   usershare owner only = yes

            # server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field
                server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)

            # Windows Internet Name Serving Support Section:
            # WINS Support - Tells the NMBD component of Samba to enable its WINS Server
            #   wins support = no

            # WINS Server - Tells the NMBD components of Samba to be a WINS Client
            # Note: Samba can be either a WINS Server, or a WINS Client, but NOT both
            ;   wins server = w.x.y.z

            # This will prevent nmbd to search for NetBIOS names through DNS.
                dns proxy = no

            #### Networking ####

            # The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
            # This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
            # interface names are normally preferred
            ;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0

            # Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
            # 'interfaces' option above to use this.
            # It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine is
            # not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself.  However, this
            # option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
            ;   bind interfaces only = yes



            #### Debugging/Accounting ####

            # This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
            # that connects
                log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

            # Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).
                max log size = 1000

            # If you want Samba to only log through syslog then set the following
            # parameter to 'yes'.
            #   syslog only = no

            # We want Samba to log a minimum amount of information to syslog. Everything
            # should go to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd} instead. If you want to log
            # through syslog you should set the following parameter to something higher.
                syslog = 0

            # Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
                panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d


            ####### Authentication #######

            # Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
            # values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
            # domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
            # directory domain controller". 
            #
            # Most people will want "standalone sever" or "member server".
            # Running as "active directory domain controller" will require first
            # running "samba-tool domain provision" to wipe databases and create a
            # new domain.
                server role = standalone server

            # If you are using encrypted passwords, Samba will need to know what
            # password database type you are using.  
            ;   passdb backend = tdbsam

                obey pam restrictions = yes

            # This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
            # password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
            # passdb is changed.
                unix password sync = yes

            # For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
            # parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
            # sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).
                passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
                passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

            # This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
            # when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
            # 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.
                pam password change = yes

            # This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped
            # to anonymous connections
                map to guest = bad user

                   security = share

            ########## Domains ###########

            #
            # The following settings only takes effect if 'server role = primary
            # classic domain controller', 'server role = backup domain controller'
            # or 'domain logons' is set 
            #

            # It specifies the location of the user's
            # profile directory from the client point of view) The following
            # required a [profiles] share to be setup on the samba server (see
            # below)
            ;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
            # Another common choice is storing the profile in the user's home directory
            # (this is Samba's default)
            #   logon path = \\%N\%U\profile

            # The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
            # It specifies the location of a user's home directory (from the client
            # point of view)
            ;   logon drive = H:
            #   logon home = \\%N\%U

            # The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
            # It specifies the script to run during logon. The script must be stored
            # in the [netlogon] share
            # NOTE: Must be store in 'DOS' file format convention
            ;   logon script = logon.cmd

            # This allows Unix users to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
            # RPC pipe.  The example command creates a user account with a disabled Unix
            # password; please adapt to your needs
            ; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u

            # This allows machine accounts to be created on the domain controller via the 
            # SAMR RPC pipe.  
            # The following assumes a "machines" group exists on the system
            ; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u

            # This allows Unix groups to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
            # RPC pipe.  
            ; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g

            ############ Misc ############

            # Using the following line enables you to customise your configuration
            # on a per machine basis. The %m gets replaced with the netbios name
            # of the machine that is connecting
            ;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m

            # Some defaults for winbind (make sure you're not using the ranges
            # for something else.)
            ;   idmap uid = 10000-20000
            ;   idmap gid = 10000-20000
            ;   template shell = /bin/bash

            # Setup usershare options to enable non-root users to share folders
            # with the net usershare command.

            # Maximum number of usershare. 0 (default) means that usershare is disabled.
            ;   usershare max shares = 100

            # Allow users who've been granted usershare privileges to create
            # public shares, not just authenticated ones
                usershare allow guests = yes

            #======================= Share Definitions =======================

            # Un-comment the following (and tweak the other settings below to suit)
            # to enable the default home directory shares. This will share each
            # user's home directory as \\server\username
            ;[homes]
            ;   comment = Home Directories
            ;   browseable = no

            # By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
            # next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.
            ;   read only = yes

            # File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
            # create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
            ;   create mask = 0700

            # Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
            # create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
            ;   directory mask = 0700

            # By default, \\server\username shares can be connected to by anyone
            # with access to the samba server.
            # Un-comment the following parameter to make sure that only "username"
            # can connect to \\server\username
            # This might need tweaking when using external authentication schemes
            ;   valid users = %S

            # Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons
            # (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
            ;[netlogon]
            ;   comment = Network Logon Service
            ;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
            ;   guest ok = yes
            ;   read only = yes

            # Un-comment the following and create the profiles directory to store
            # users profiles (see the "logon path" option above)
            # (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
            # The path below should be writable by all users so that their
            # profile directory may be created the first time they log on
            ;[profiles]
            ;   comment = Users profiles
            ;   path = /home/samba/profiles
            ;   guest ok = no
            ;   browseable = no
            ;   create mask = 0600
            ;   directory mask = 0700

            [printers]
                comment = All Printers
                browseable = no
                path = /var/spool/samba
                printable = yes
            ;   guest ok = no
            ;   read only = yes
                create mask = 0700

            # Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
            # printer drivers
            [print$]
                comment = Printer Drivers
                path = /var/lib/samba/printers
            ;   browseable = yes
            ;   read only = yes
            ;   guest ok = no
            # Uncomment to allow remote administration of Windows print drivers.
            # You may need to replace 'lpadmin' with the name of the group your
            # admin users are members of.
            # Please note that you also need to set appropriate Unix permissions
            # to the drivers directory for these users to have write rights in it
            ;   write list = root, @lpadmin

            [Daten]
                path = /media/Daten
                writeable = yes
            ;   browseable = yes
                guest ok = yes
```

I made some terminal things, following the advice given in similar posts, but to be honest, I didn't know what I am doing and can't repeat it here.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on what you currently have and how you are using it because I'm confused about what you have...  To me your description sounds a bit like "I've got 2 cars and I fiddled around a bit but I still can start only one engine!"  ;-)

Comment: You're a developer!  What do you have?  What are you trying to accomplish? What is your problem?  (well, that one is clear: you have a volume mount that asks for a password and you don't want any!)

Comment: Yes, I'm a developer, but I have no clue about linux. I will edit my question, trying to be more precise, but I am not very shure, what you need to know. Please ask me, if I leave out something important.

Comment: I'm still confused at to what you are trying to accomplish so I'll try to rephrase what I understood from this conversation: you want to have a common file share between a Linux and a Windows computer without *typing* any password (if *can* be a password that is fixed in a batch file or bash script) and you don't care which is the server: Linux or Windows, as long as the |@#¼ thing works! ;-)  Is this more or less correct?

Comment: Correct! Plus at the moment I can't connect even if I type the password, because it is not accepted.

Comment: Bear with me: Somewhere in your question you say that this is working: you have a share on the Ubuntu machine and you can access it from the Windows computer...  So what's the problem there???  (we know what the problem is the other way around)

Comment: I have no problem accessing Ubuntu from my windows computer. I just wanted to say that it works in one direction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19078/discussion-between-fabby-and-lord-mord).

Answer (score 1):

smb.conf is a red herring ; this sets up Samba on your local box - ie, serving shared folders up, not accessing them.

Try from a terminal

```
sudo mount -t cifs \
           -o user=windowsuser,domain=windowsdomain,uid=ubuntuusername \
           //windowsmachine/sharedfolder /mnt
```

Which should prompt you for your sudo password, then your Windows one.

The current (as of 14.04) "Connect to Server" UI has been "simplified" (thanks, GNOME!) and it makes it harder to connect to a Windows share than was previously the case.

You can also try using an smb:// link from the "Connect to Server" dialog in Nautilus though

```
smb://domain;user@windowsmachine/share
```

Comment: I can't get that to work. What is the username? I tried the name of the Ubuntu user. What is my domain? The Windows workgroup name?

Comment: You need to use an account that the Windows machine will authenticate, that is authorized to access the share. That would be the Windows user name, and the workgroup name (which is WORKGROUP by default..) ; the uid part mounts the share as owned by a local Ubuntu user (so you don't have to be root to access the files)

Comment: It says wrong fs type. I assume that that means filesystem. I already installed a package the makes NTFS filesystems readable.

Comment: Excellent. I did something like smb://workgroup:Administrator@myserver.local/mystuff and worked perfectly